# Как передать id объекта в текстовое поле? django 2

Tags: python, django

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку "Добавить комментарий" в текстовое поле шаблона добавления комментария в строку ИД поста  записывался id поста, с которого юзер перешел на эту страницу?

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField('Текст комментария', default='Текст комментария')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, default=7, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField('ИД поста', default=1)
```

views.py

```
class CreateCommentsView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
model = Comments
fields = ['comment', 'object_id']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
path('comments/add/', views.CreateCommentsView.as_view(), name='comments-add')
```

Вот скрин
[image: скрин]

Comment: В адресной строке можно ид поста передать, например.

Comment: @МистерФикс Это то понятно, но как сделать так, чтобы тотже ид из адресной строки выводился в текстовое поле?

Comment: Так из адресной строки его и взять. Либо из GET. Тут как уже реализуешь.

Comment: Если из get-параметров, то это request.GET, там словарь.

Comment: @МистерФикс можешь скинуть кусок кода, как это сделать? У меня просто не получается это реализовать через request.GET, а из адресной строки вообще хз как брать.

Comment: @Рыбка JS в помощь

Comment: @Рыбка, это веб надо изучать. Тут всё постепенно.